# How can we bind values from material2 slider ?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using material 2 slider, Unfortunately the ngModel feature is not yet released. Then my question is how can i bind and take the values to the slider ?

```
<md-slider min="0" max="100"></md-slider>
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: NgModel is supported as I just tested two way binding for sliders. I have a  demo repo available at https://github.com/gelliott181/md-slider-test

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/slider/README.md
but here they are saying that this feature is not yet implemented

Comment: I saw that when I was checking the demo bits I pulled the code from. That doc file has a commit hash dating to 23 days ago. Latest slider commit was 2 days ago. It works just fine.

Comment: Even the Angular team piles on documentation debt when they're pushing hard.

Comment: can you put this info as answers, I will help some others too.